# PostgreSQL-12.1 :: Streaming Replication Error

Tags: database-backups, master-slave, pg-restore, postgresql-12

I have set up streaming replication on *PostgreSQL 12.1*

The master and slave are configured as below and *WAL* files are accumulating on the master.

However, something is wrong as I get complaints that the *WAL* files are missing after a `pg_restore` on `MASTER`

**MASTER**

```
postgres@srvm:~$ 2019-12-20 16:35:07.910 CET [1334] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:35:12.920 CET [1338] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:35:17.925 CET [1340] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:35:22.932 CET [1362] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:35:27.935 CET [1364] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:35:32.942 CET [1365] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:35:37.948 CET [1366] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:35:42.954 CET [1367] replicator@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
```

**SLAVE**

```
postgres@srvs:~$ 2019-12-20 16:36:53.027 CET [21978] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1/76000000 on timeline 1
2019-12-20 16:36:53.027 CET [21978] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:36:58.029 CET [21979] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1/76000000 on timeline 1
2019-12-20 16:36:58.029 CET [21979] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:37:03.040 CET [21980] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1/76000000 on timeline 1
2019-12-20 16:37:03.040 CET [21980] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
2019-12-20 16:37:08.042 CET [21981] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1/76000000 on timeline 1
2019-12-20 16:37:08.042 CET [21981] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000000100000076 has already been removed
```

Then the `pg_basebackup` is run and the slave started.

The slave has all the data as of the time of the backup, but no new data from the WAL files, and the error above.

```
max_wal_senders = 10          
wal_keep_segments = 120
```

What have I mis-configured? Do we need to enabled `archive_mode = on` for streaming replication?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration for streaming replication:

Master config

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,[IP_ADDRESS_OF_PRIMARY_ON_LAN]'              # what IP address(es) to listen on; 
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'
max_wal_senders = 5
primary_conninfo = 'host=[REPLICA_IP] port=5432 user=replication password=[REPLICATION PASSWORD]'
hot_standby = on

max_wal_senders = 10          
wal_keep_segments = 48
```

Slave config:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,[IP_ADDRESS_OF_REPLIACA_ON_LAN]'              # what IP address(es) to listen on; 
max_connections = 100 # Ensure that this value is the same as the primary's
wal_level = 'replica'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'
max_wal_senders = 5
primary_conninfo = 'host=[PRIMARY_IP] port=5432 user=replication password=[REPLICATION PASSWORD]'
hot_standby = on

max_wal_senders = 10          
wal_keep_segments = 48
```

I set up my server using the following resource: https://www.gab.lc/articles/postgresql-12-replication/